# Why are Accented Capital Letters not well decoded in QRCODE?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, languages, accents, qrcode

Double accented capital letters, such as ÙÇ, ÙÉ, ÀÇ, and  ÈÏ, are not well decoded in a qrcode. Is there a way to fix that ?

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % if this package is not present, the accented text outside the qrcode disappear
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[forget]{qrcode}
\begin{document}

The following qrcodes work well: \\[20pt]
À \qrcode[]{À} ~~ 
É \qrcode[]{É} ~~
Ù \qrcode[]{Ù} ~~ 
Ç \qrcode[]{Ç} \\[20pt]
È \qrcode[]{È} ~~ 
Ï \qrcode[]{Ï} ~~
ÀÉ \qrcode[]{AÉ} ~~ 
Ù Ç \qrcode[]{Ù\ Ç} \\[20pt]
àçéùï \qrcode[]{àçéùï}\\[20pt]

The accented characters are not well decoded in the following qrcodes:\\[20pt]
ÙÇ \qrcode[]{ÙÇ} ~~ 
ÙÉ \qrcode[]{ÙÉ} ~~ 
ÀÇ \qrcode[]{ÀÇ} ~~ 
ÈÏ \qrcode[]{ÈÏ} \\[20pt] 
ÀÉÙÇ \qrcode[]{ÀÉÙÇ} ~~ 
àùéèçïÀÉÙÇÈÏ \qrcode[]{àùéèçïÀÉÙÇÈÏ} 

\newpage

The following qrcodes work well when the Accented Capital Letters are separated by a space: \\[20pt]

Ù Ç \qrcode[]{Ù\ Ç} ~~ 
Ù É \qrcode[]{Ù\ É} ~~ 
À Ç \qrcode[]{À\ Ç} ~~ 
È Ï \qrcode[]{È\ Ï} \\[20pt] 
À É Ù Ç \qrcode[]{À\ É\ Ù\ Ç}\\[20pt]

The following qrcode translates (?) into asian characters when the Accented Capital Letters are separated by a space: \\[20pt]

àùéèçï À É Ù Ç È Ï \qrcode[]{àùéèçï\ À\ É\ Ù\ Ç\ È\ Ï} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which engine do you use? LuaLaTeX or XeTeX? As well, using anything but lower ASCII in a QR code sounds like a bad idea, similar to using it in your username or password. You can only expect troubles everywhere (not just in their generation, in their reading as well).

Comment: The engine is LuaLateX

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), it looks like QR code does not support unicode directly. So it depends on what are you encoding? A URL so `À` goes to `%C3%80`? A piece of text with specific decoder? Do you want to change to more efficient encoding like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)?

Comment: I have updated my code to show that the accented capital letters are well decoded when alone or separated by a space: so, "À" is perfect alone, but not when side by side with Ç (with a few exceptions like ÀÉ). Why aren't they well decoded when they are close to each other ? Does an accented capital letter need more space to be well decoded ?

Comment: As mentioned by Symbol1 (see answer below), "ÀÉ" doesn't work well: in my example,  "AÉ" is in the QRcode instead of "ÀÉ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, QR code does not support Unicode directly. And the implement of `qrcode` package uses the following lines to convert characters to number:

> ```
> \def\qr@encode@ascii@recursive(#1,#2#3){%
>   % #1 = hex codes translated so far
>   % #2 = next plaintext character to translate
>   % #3 = remainder of plaintext
>   \edef\qr@testii{#2}%
>   \ifx\qr@testii\qr@relax%
>     % All done!
>     \g@addto@macro\qr@codetext{#1}%
>   \else%
>     % Another character to translate.
>     \edef\qr@asciicode{\number`#2}%
>     \qr@decimaltohex[2]{\qr@newhexcodes}{\qr@asciicode}%
>     \edef\qr@argument{(#1\qr@newhexcodes,#3)}%
>     %\show\qr@argument
>     \xa\qr@encode@ascii@recursive\qr@argument%
>   \fi%
> }%
> ```

As you can see, `` \number`#2 `` is a macro that

- sends `A` to `41`
- sends `É` to `c9`
- sends `Ù` to `d9`
- sends `Ç` to `c7`
- and so on...

### Does `qrcode` works well?

It almost does. Those characters are converted to corresponding numbers and hence lead to good QR images.

For instance, the raw data of `ÙÇ` is

> ```
> 40 2d 9c 70 ec 11 ec 11   ec
> ```

where

- `4` means [Byte encoding (8 bits per character)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Encoding);
- `02` means there are three characters;
- `d9` is `Ù`; and
- `c7` is `Ç`.

In case of `Ù Ç`, the raw data is

> ```
> 40 3d 92 0c 70 ec 11 ec   11
> ```

where

- `4` means [Byte encoding (8 bits per character)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Encoding);
- `03` means there are two characters;
- `d9` is `Ù`;
- `20` is the space; and
- `c7` is `Ç`.

### So, what's wrong?

Things masses up during decoding. Turns out that decoders recognizes `d920c7`= `Ù Ç` but not `d9c7`=`ÙÇ`. I cannot explain this. And the last case is even funnier:

> ```
> 41 2e 0f 9e 9e 8e 7e f2   0c 02 0c 92 0d 92 0c 72   0c 82 0c f0 ec 11
> ```

The first recognizable character `e0f9` is `瓊` in Shift JIS, an encoding supported by QR code. Thus the decoder will change to Shift JIS and output `瓊鳧鉐 ﾀ ﾉ ﾙ ﾇ ﾈ ﾏ` as result.

### But why `ÀÉ` behaves well?

No it does not. The raw data is

> ```
> 40 24 1c 90 ec 11 ec 11   ec
> ```

Which is `AÉ` but not `ÀÉ`.

### How to solve it?

First of all if you are encoding French, characters like [`Œ`, `œ`, and the very rare `Ÿ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Languages_commonly_supported_but_with_incomplete_coverage) may cause fail. You probably need to rewrite the macro mentioned above.

Otherwise if you are satisfies with ASCII, you need to force your decoder reads characters after 0xFF=127. Nothing to do with TeX here.

Comment: Very clear and informative answer. Thanks !